# Split the screen on android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I've seen several tablet apps that split the screen into two parts. Usually a menu and and a main window. I tried to google something about it, but couldn't find anything. Is there an out of the box solution for this, or do I have build it on my own?

Comment: @TimThomas Don't worry it usually takes me a while, but if I find something useful I finally accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the article on [**multi-pane layouts**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html) on the Android Design site. It should help clarify the idea behind it.

As for actually implementing them, you'll have to use [`Fragment`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)s. Here are a couple [tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) to get you [started](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html).

Answer (score 1):

The sdk code samples are most likely already on your computer, and can be accessed through the "new Android project..." wizard of Eclipse.

Or if you own an Honeycomb tablet and just want to play around with the ApiDemos samples without looking at the code, you can just search for ApiDemos in the Google Play Store and download the one ApiDemos project that has four to five stars next to it.

On the tablet itself, many of the ApiDemos will be double-listed, but that's because the first one is usually the pre-honeycomb version and the second one is the post-honeycomb version.